# Why is my file not updating within the program?

Tags: python

Trying to delete lines from a file in python, works just fine but it doesnt update until i restart the program... how can i make it where it removes the line and updates within the program, I am using queues since i'm sending api requests with items to send them concurrently thank you.

Code example:

```
class auto_claimer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.username_list = [user.replace("\n", "") for user in open("database.txt")]
        self.mutex = Lock() 
        self.userQ = Queue()

    def reloadQ(self):
        for i in self.username_list:
            self.userQ.put(i)
        #print(len(self.username_list), "Words Successfully added to Queue")

    def Queue(self):
        while True:
            if self.userQ.qsize() < len(self.username_list) / 2:
                self.reloadQ()

    def delete(self, item):
        with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        with open("database.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != item:
                    f.write(line)
                    f.flush()
        print("Successfully removed {} from the text file".format(item))
```

Comment: What is the `it` in `it doesnt update`?

Comment: like when i remove something from a text file, it removes it successfully but the program still tells me that the item is still in the file

Comment: How does `the program still tells me that the item is still in the file`?

Comment: because im sending api requests with the usernames in the file, when a username is avaliable it removes it from the file, but when a user became avaliable it just kept spamming ""Successfully removed ... from the text file"

Comment: which means the file is the same from when the program opened it.

Comment: Well, your `delete()` method will report any `item` removed from the file even if its not there.

Answer (score 1):

When you keep open a file for reading and then open it again to overwrite its entire content in the same scope without closing it - is a bad practice anyway.

For the most part, many changes to files in python do not go into effect until after the file is closed, so if your script edits, leaves open, and reads a file, it won't see the edits. So, close the file each time you complete reading or writing it.

```
def delete(self, item):
        with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
        with open("database.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != item:
                    f.write(line)
                    f.flush()
            f.close()
        print("Successfully removed {} from the text file".format(item))
```